# Mysql count(*) is failing me

Tags: php, mysql

```html
if(!$this->MakeProcedure("StupidProcedure", "OUT msg VARCHAR(25)" )){
            echo "could not create procedure";
  }

if(!$this->db->query("SET @msg = ''") || !$this->db->query("CALL StupidProcedure(@msg)")){
          echo "CALL to StupidProcedure  failed:";
}  else   {
    $res= $this->db->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out");
     $row = $res->fetch();
                echo $row['_p_out']." counted columns ";
}     ​
```

I have tables authors and publishers within mysql DB. They both have ISBN
Column in common. I then issued a call (through php) to a stored procedure
That contains the following code:

```
BEGIN   
DECLARE count int;

                    SELECT count (*) FROM 
                                    (
                                       SELECT distinct
                                       table_name
                                       FROM information_schema.columns
                                       WHERE table_name IN ('authors', ‘publishers’)
                                       AND column_name = 'ISBN'
                                       and table_schema = 'myDB'
                                    )any_alias
                    INTO count;
                    SELECT count INTO msg;      /*just to debug counter*/
END
```

Basically, I want the above snippet to return 2 as counted number of tables that 
have ISBN column in common (to reflect in count variable). Unfortunately,
count is always returning 0 in spite of multiple - checking that ISBN column is
there (with phpmyadmin). Why is count(*) behaving strangely ? or is there 
a special .ini configuration that I must set ?

here is my test driver:

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `Res = $this->db->query(...)` /`$row = $res->fetch()` -> `Res` vs `$res` a copy/paste error here?

Comment: `Res` is not a php variable - `Res = $this->db->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out");`. It is missing a `$` -> `$Res`. Then on the next line you try to access `$res` -> `$row = $res->fetch();`. Where do you set `$res` before accessing it with method `->fetch()`? Should `Res` in `Res = $this->db->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out");` be `$res = $this->db->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out");`? Is this just an error here on SO, or is `Res = ...` actually in your code?

Comment: ooops ! it was a typo error from my text editor . so whats the wayout of my problem@ Sean?

Comment: You didn't declare `msg` as an OUT parameter...

Comment: @Mark i did. i just didn't feel its necessary addin it to the above code. u may now see it upon re-edit. my instinct tells me that the problem lies within mysql, not my code. or what do u think?

Answer (score 0):

Woooow ! Finally I’ve got it. Here’s the sql code snippet that does the dirty fix:

```html
BEGIN   
DECLARE count int; 
                    SELECT count(1)
                    FROM information_schema.columns
                    WHERE table_name IN ('authors', 'publishers')
                    AND column_name = 'ISBN'
                    AND table_schema = 'test'   
                    INTO count;
                    SELECT count INTO msg;      /*just to debug counter*/
END
//PRINT ‘Thank you guys !’
​
```

Comment: in actual sense, the solution came when i checked to be sure quotes appear as '' in publishers as against ‘, which caused count to malfunction.